# using "all" and "any" keyword in python gives unexpected output?

Tags: python, if-statement, any

I have this following code for calculating prime numbers

```
def isPrime(n):
   if (n==2):
      return True
   elif n<=1 or n%2==0:
      return False
   else:
      for i in xrange(3,n/2, 2):
          if n%i:
            return False
   return True


mylist = [6,9]

mylist2= [3,5,7,11,12]

if not any(isPrime(x) for x in mylist):
       print "No primes in list"

if not all(isPrime(x) for x in mylist2):
       print "Not all are primes numbers"
```

when I run this program, I get

```
python calculate_primes.py 
Not all are primes numbers
```

I do not get the output of `No primes in list`. but if i remove element `9` in `mylist` and have only `6`, it works fine.

```
python calculate_primes.py 
No primes in list
Not all are primes numbers
```

Either something wrong with my code or I am using the `any` wrongly?
some tips here please

Comment: did you even try printing `isPrime(9)`?

Comment: Check the answers but in addition you also only need to loop from 3 to int(math.sqrt(n)), n/2 is excessive. To further improve efficiency try reading up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: I know the `sieve` algorithm, but I do not know that `int(math.sqrt(n)` is sufficient. can you explain why?

Comment: In all pairs of factors for a positive integer, one must be less than or equal to the square root of the number. Proof is easy by a counterexample leading to a contradiction. So if you've reached the square root of the number without finding an integer factor, you know it's prime.

Comment: It must be `int(math.sqrt(n))+1`, I guess since without adding 1 it did not work

Comment: `xrange` excludes its end argument - `int(math.sqrt(n))` is the last possible factor you need to check, but it won't be checked if you give it to `xrange` as the ending point rather than `int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1`. But that's because of how `xrange` works rather than the math.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Thats correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something wrong with your `isPrime()` function.  Within the `for` loop you are currently returning `False` if the condition `n%i` evaluates to True, but this will only happen if `n` is *not* evenly divisible by `i`.  Instead you should be using `if not n%i` or `if n%i == 0`.

Comment: I need a coffee break definitely. I cant afford to do this mistake!

Answer (score 3):

You want `if n%i == 0`, not `if n%i` since i divides n only if the mod is 0.  Your code is returning false when i does not divide n.